# How to merge/pick/update specific parts from different repositories

Tags: git, git-merge

## The scenario

My **main** project has the following text (code actually):

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. (...) Cras ullamcorper in lorem nec finibus.

Suspendisse . (...) Vestibulum ex nunc, facilisis pulvinar lorem eu, convallis volutpat tortor.

In hac habitasse platea dictumst. (...) Cras quis ex accumsan, aliquet odio pulvinar, pellentesque ante.
```

My friend has a **side** project (also in a different repository):

```
Fusce iaculis vulputate rhoncus. (...) Duis ac gravida nisl.

Suspendisse potenti. (...) Vestibulum ex nunc, facilisis pulvinar lorem eu, convallis volutpat tortor.

Nulla a nibh egestas, condimentum erat vitae, auctor est. (...) Sed aliquet mi eget nunc ullamcorper egestas.
```

## Objective

I want to pick only the second line (portion of the code) to merge into my **main** branch because it has a fixed content. All the other content should be ignored.
I've already added his repository:

```
git remote add side-project /foo/path
git pull side-project master:john-project
```

I have no idea of what to use, if it is either merge, or cherry-pick.

## The real life

My project can make use of a specific function from a different repository. Whenever the other repository is updated, I would pull the function with updated/patches.

Answer (score 0):

You can't cherry-pick lines of code to merge with git. Besides the second line, one of you should generally have the right lines that you want e.g. the 'master' branch or main repository.

In this situation, I think it's best if your friend pulls your code (since it seems like the main repository) and then merges it with his code. Fix any merge conflicts, etc, so that it looks like this in his repository:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. (...) Cras ullamcorper in lorem nec finibus.

Suspendisse potenti. (...) Vestibulum ex nunc, facilisis pulvinar lorem eu, convallis volutpat tortor.

In hac habitasse platea dictumst. (...) Cras quis ex accumsan, aliquet odio pulvinar, pellentesque ante.
```

(1st and 3rd lines are from your repo, 2nd is from his)

Then, he can submit a pull request to your main project and it will have the fixed code, where only the second line is changed.

Comment: Let's say I have the main repository and he just wrote some dummy random phrases (piece of code) and I wanted to pick his code and pull to my repository. For example, if someone has a useful library, but I want just some portion of the code.

But "You can't cherry-pick lines of code" answers everything. Thank you!